# why $ r_i$ is smaller than $r_{n+1}$ and why $r_j$ is larger than $r_{n+1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have some confusion in Rudin Book

My confusion given below marked  in red line
[image]

**My thinking**  : If  $r_i$  will be largest  one then $r_i > r_{n+1}$ and  if $r_j$  will be smallest  one then $ r_{n+1} > r_j$

**My confusion** : why $ r_i$ is smaller than $r_{n+1}$  and why $r_j$ is larger than  $r_{n+1}$ ?

Comment: By “the largest one which is smaller than $r_{n+1}$” they don’t mean that the largest number happens to be smaller than $r_{n+1}$. They mean that you pick the largest number only among those that are smaller than $r_{n+1}$.

Comment: okks got its  @EikeSchulte

Answer (score 1):

It's  mean that  $$r_i < r_{n+1}  < r_j$$  where  $r_j$ is the smallest among $r_1,...,r_n$ above $r_{n+1}$ while  $r_i$ is the largest among $r_1,....,r_n$ below  $r_{n+1}$